# Typing in any command into terminal returns with command not found

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, path

Someone told me to post here for help.
I know this topic has been discussed before, but I've looked at the solutions for these questions and usually the response goes along the lines

```
Run these commands in terminal:
export PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"
```

After that, the commands work. However, they stop working if you close that terminal window and then reopen it later.

When I type in

```
echo $PATH
```

I get

```
/usr/local/Cellar/qt5/4.4.1/bin
```

I found out that Cellar is part of Homebrew. I uninstalled it, but I still get the `/usr/local/Cellar/qt5/4.4.1/bin` when I type in `echo $PATH`.

All I know is that typing in any command like unzip, git, chmod, tar doesn't work. How do I fix this? I don't know anything about this type of stuff, so please explain like I'm five.

Answer (score 3):

First you should run:

```
grep "qt5/4.4.1/bin" /etc/profile ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login ~/.profile 2> /dev/null
```

It will print the name of the file which contains a line with the string `qt5/4.4.1/bin`. If no results appear, try with `qt5` in the argument.

Most likely it will look like:

```
/Users/<username>/<filename>:export PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/qt5/4.4.1/bin
```

some part might be different.

Then you should open the file (given to the left of `:`), find the line, and comment (add `#` at the beginning of the line).

This way the default `PATH` variable as defined by `/etc/paths` and further modifications should not get overwritten.

---

> I found out that Cellar is part of Homebrew. I uninstalled it

You shouldn't do this. First, it's not the problem with Homebrew (the package manager) itself, but one package (`qt5`) installed by Homebrew.

Second, uninstalling Homebrew will not reverse the change that was made by the package.

Comment: Why not just change that line to `export PATH="${PATH}:/usr/local/Cellar/qt5/4.4.1/bin"`? Why remove the directory from the PATH instead of just appending it?

Comment: I suggested commenting out. One reason might be, because OP is not exactly sure about qt5. If it will be installed again as some dependency with a different version number it would be harder to debug if something broke. OP won't remember this manual action. If something breaks immediately after commenting out, the cause-reason will be obvious.

Comment: Fair enough. And that wasn't criticism, by the way, I'd already upvoted. I was just wondering why you chose to suggest the OP remove something which, presumably, they want to have.